# Pandas using datarange to get day of week for each date

Tags: python, date, pandas

I amusing pandas to generate a data frame to produce a list of dates that range from 2012-2015. What I want to do is to be able to pull the day of the week such as :

```
2012-01-01    Sunday
2012-01-02    Monday
2012-01-03    Tuesday
```

This is what I have started and a little bit on how I want to finish it. However I cannot seem to get the to_datetime so that I can proceed to get dayofweek.

```
    import pandas as pd

    i = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2015-12-31')
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(year = i.year, month = i.month, day = i.day))
    df = pd.to_datetime(df.year*10000 + df.month*100 + df.day, format = '%Y%m%d')
    df['weekday'] = df.dt.dayofweek

    days = {0:'Mon',1:'Tues',2:'Weds',3:'Thurs',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}

    df['day_of_week'] = df['day_of_week'].apply(lambda x: days[x])
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on how to tackle this data frame so I can get this to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a list comprehension together with [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
i = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2015-12-31')
df = pd.DataFrame({'day_of_week': [ts.strftime("%A") for ts in i]}, index=i)
df.head()

           day_of_week
2012-01-01      Sunday
2012-01-02      Monday
2012-01-03     Tuesday
2012-01-04   Wednesday
2012-01-05    Thursday
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
import pandas as pd

i = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2015-12-31')
i.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%A'))
```